# Redirect 301 htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would like to redirect all my pdf files from a specific folder (here `toto`) to the root of another folder (here `tata`), e.g.:

```
www.mywebsite/toto/fic1.pdf                   -> www.mywebsite/tata/
www.mywebsite/toto/fic2.pdf                   -> www.mywebsite/tata/
www.mywebsite/toto/fic3.pdf                   -> www.mywebsite/tata/
www.mywebsite/toto/fic4.pdf                   -> www.mywebsite/tata/
www.mywebsite/toto/sousDossier/fic4.pdf       -> www.mywebsite/tata/
```

I've written one line per file but it is not pretty ...

```
RedirectPermanent /toto/fic1.pdf http://www.mywebsite/tata/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /?toto/.*\.pdf$ /tata/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks but it will redirect www.monsite/toto/a.pdf to /tata/a.pdf won't it ? I just want /tata/ without a.pdf

Comment: No, it will redirect just to www.yoursite.com/tata/

Comment: May be the mod_rewrite is off? It works fine with xampp on my laptop.

Comment: Try adding full domain name in target URL (just in case)

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^toto/[^.]+\.pdf$ tata/ [R=301,L,NC]
```